# paginate relational resource in laravel api

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-collection, laravel-resource

I have two models, `User` and `Comment`, Each `User` can have multiple `Comment`, I can call `paginate(3)` on `User` and get 3 `User` in output per page but I need same thing as `User` for comments in [UserCollection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTbdX.png).
Is it possible to limit comments that comes by `UserCollection` by paginating them too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, you just have to add in the third parameter of pageName to the paginate method to differentiate between them.

Something like:

```
$users->paginate($perPage, ['*'], 'users')
$comments->paginate($perPage, ['*'], 'comments_'. $user_id)
```

https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_paginate

Note: While you can do this, I personally would just fetch the first 3/5 comments and then have a button saying `click to load more` and then have a separate route that you call via an AJAX request to get them.

Comment: can you say which method is better to use ? which one is standard ? using ajax or using paginate?

Comment: For this instance I would use AJAX requests to fetch any extra comments because it is 10x easier and it'll have a lot more readable and scaleable code